# How to select only elements who stands close to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have html code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <div class="images">
        Some text
        <img src="image1.jpg">
        Some text
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
        Some text
        <img src="image4.jpg">
        Some text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to select only images who stands together and add a class to them.
In the example above I need to add class to the second and third images only.
How I can implement it with Jquery or Vanila JS?

Comment: why not using classes ?

Comment: `img + img` will select any image that's preceded by another image.

Comment: What is the parent element of the above code? are they the only images on the page? We need to know one of the above to give you a working code

Comment: Just HTML like: <html><head></head><body>{ code above }</body></html>

Comment: `img + img` doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/dhpqaoLx/

Comment: Your textnodes should be wrapped in span instead, this would make it really easier to target relevant imgs. Otherwise, you could filter it but you'd need to exclude white spaced textnodes, that's not that easy

Comment: See e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/pxnvzyj0/

Comment: @pawel That will only select the sibling (second image), not both.

Comment: Your specification doesn't make much sense. You say you want to select images that 'stand together' .. 'second and third images only'. Why not the 4th? (The second `image3.jpg`)

Comment: @a-wolff, thx, it works

Comment: @George OP has edited posted HTML markup

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to put `Some text` in a tag. it could be any tag you want.I choose `span` tag.

```
<span>Some text</span>
<img src="image1.jpg">
<span>Some text</span>
<img src="image2.jpg">
<img src="image3.jpg">
<img src="image3.jpg">
<span>Some text</span>
<img src="image4.jpg">
<span>Some text</span>
```

after that, you should use `.prev()` in jquery to select previous tag in selected IMGs. that because when you select images with `img+img` , it only selects the two images after the first one. so the first wanted image could not be in you selection.
I've prepared you this explanation in JSfiddle to be more clear.

```
$("img + img").addClass('red');
$("img + img").prev().addClass('red');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/linkers/dhpqaoLx/3/

obviously you can optimize your code by using variables instead of using jquery selector twice.